# Multiple Where Clauses with Same Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We have the below query running in one of our stored procedures:

```
SELECT 
    WOffice AS office,
    RIGHT(JobTitle,4) JOBTITLE,
    SUM(ISNULL(rHours,0)) AS rcount,
    SUM(ISNULL(rdollars,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(amount,0)) AS rdollars,
    CAST (DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,paydate),-1)AS DATE )AS [week] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[warehouse]
WHERE 
    paydate BETWEEN paydate AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, paydate)
    AND (paydate BETWEEN @WkStart AND @EzMaxDate)
    AND (PayDate BETWEEN @Seasonstart AND @SeasonEnd)
    AND SUBSTRING(JobTitle,1,1) LIKE '%[A-Z]%' 
GROUP BY
    WOffice, RIGHT(JobTitle, 4), DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, paydate), -1)
```

In this code, the paydate column is used in multiple where clauses. Is there a more efficient way to write the above logic in SQL?

Comment: `paydate between paydate and DATEADD(day,7,paydate)` , what are you trying to do here? its basically the same as `paydate <= DATEADD(day,7,paydate)`

Comment: General GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: @sagi I am actually grouping the table data weekwise.

Comment: the above code is executed within a CTE. during execution, ssms throws tempdb full  error. I thought optimizing the code might remove the error

Comment: @bmsqldev Even so, `paydate` will always be `>=` of `paydate` , simple logic . Its an unnecessary comparison .

Comment: @sagi and paydate <= DATEADD(day,7,paydate) is always going to be true

Comment: @sagi . that validation is not required?

Comment: i mean, even if i not give that validation the result will be same?

Comment: @Paparazzi You are right, didn't even look at that second part, this whole condition doesn't do anything. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @bmsqldev Yes, thats what I'm saying, if you'll tell me what you want to achieve, I'll tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @bmsqldev  How can something that is always true be a validation?  Is 1 = 1 as validation?    Show some effort.

Comment: @Paparazzi. that was not my intention. what I tried was to group the day wise data into week wise. so i think a validation to take out a week each time is required.

Comment: Really you don't get paydate BETWEEN paydate AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, paydate) is always true?   You are a database developer for a living?

Comment: @ Paparazzi  ok agree. thanks for showing the blunders in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for `paydate` is fine.  If SQL Server supported `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`, you might be able to find other elegant solutions.

Handling multiple overlapping time periods is tricky.  I cannot say that your logic is *correct*.  But, if your intention is to get the overlap for the different periods, then it is correct.

As a note, the logic for `JOBTITLE` is overkill.  Either:

```
JobTitle LIKE '[A-Z]%'
```

or:

```
LEFT(JobTitle, 1) BETWEEN 'A' and 'Z'
```

I prefer the first approach, even since I started to like `LIKE` again.

Comment: i used the logic for checking multiple date validations paydate.